# Не отображать прослойку между первой колонкой в DataGrid.

Tags: datagrid, c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio

Здравствуйте.

На картинке изображён DataGrid, красным обведена прослойка перед первой колонкой.
Как мне убрать эту прослойку, чтобы DataGrid со строками был как ListView?

[image: http://s010.radikal.ru/i311/1411/4f/2172c18f5b4c.gif]

Comment: @updat, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Это заголовки строк. Можно отображать только заголовки столбцов: `HeadersVisibility="Column"`.

Answer (score 0):

В свойствах `dataGridView` измени `RowHeadersVisible` на `false`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]